# Sound Blaster Live! CT4850 doesn't work, driver installation?

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

Well, my Sound Blaster Live! card doesn't work in Ubuntu, even though it's recognized under the sound settings.

I tested each of the options, (It's just selections between Digital and Analog W or W/O Amplifers,) and none of them worked.

I went looking for a new driver and found [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man4/snd_emu10k1.4freebsd.html).  It supports my card's Chipset, so I downloaded it, extracted it, and it gave me a .freebsd file.

Could someone walk me through what to do with it?  It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have a freebsd formatted hard disk, i don't think the .freebsd file will work in anyway. I could be wrong. Are you trying to get sound out to speakers with Ubuntu? Just trying to understand your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I'm not being descriptive enough. Ubuntu detects that I have a sound card plugged in, and exactly what model it is, but doesn't output any sound.

Comment: OKAY. So, apparently, I go to watch a tutorial video on Youtube for something I'm working on, not expecting any sound, when it actually starts playing the audio. I go into the sound settings to test the drivers, and they work perfectly now. Any idea as to why it randomly started working, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in order for drivers to take effect, you may need to restart the machine; or, it can take a few tries of tinkering with restarting the applications before the new hardware gets picked up. Usually, if you have the correct drivers and you restart, the hardware will start working.

If things still do not work, you may have the wrong drivers.